# python web scraping from a site

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hi i use BeautifulSoup to catch a {'class':'course-card__title'} from https://maktabkhooneh.org/plus/
i now i want to find all (*THIS*) THIS and print it my code is:

```py
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://maktabkhooneh.org/plus/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'course-card__title'})
print(results)
x = re.findall(r'\<div class=\'course-card__title\'>(\w+)\<\/div\>',results)
print(x)
```

but i have error can someone help me?

Comment: `[el.text for el in results]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you really want the regex here, I guess. You would likely want to loop through the `results`.

#### Test 1

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://maktabkhooneh.org/plus/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'course-card__title'})
for item in results:
    print(item.text)
```

#### Output 1

```
آموزش تحلیل داده با زبان برنامه نویسی R (مقدماتی)
IELTS: Listening
آموزش تحليل تكنيكال مقدماتی
آموزش برنامه‌نویسی با پایتون (پیشرفته)
General English: Beginner
Grammar for IELTS
آموزش میکروکنترلر ARM
آموزش پایتون مقدماتی
```

---

But if you do, maybe you'd wanted to wrap your input to `re.findall()` with a `str()`:

#### Test 2

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://maktabkhooneh.org/plus/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'course-card__title'})
for item in results:
    x = re.findall(
        r'<div class="course-card__title">([^<]*)</div>', str(item))
    print(x)
```

#### Output 2

```
['آموزش تحلیل داده با زبان برنامه نویسی R (مقدماتی)']
['IELTS: Listening']
['آموزش تحليل تكنيكال مقدماتی']
['آموزش برنامه\u200cنویسی با پایتون (پیشرفته)']
['General English: Beginner']
['Grammar for IELTS']
```

Comment: thanks it helps me a lot.Now i know what to do.